# Matlab unclearable variables

Tags: matlab

I need to run some script many times in for loop. This script has got clear statement in the begginig and generates some outpot vector. I would like to save the vectors from all iteretions to a text file together with the number of iteration. And that is impossible, because clear statment always clears the number of iteration. Is it any way to achieve an unclearable variable (variable which is not cleared with clear command)?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Use [`clearvars`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html)`-except keepVariables` instead of [`clear`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html).

Comment: Remove the `clear` statement altogether.

Comment: Using a script here is bad design. Convert the script to a function, and call the function in your for loop!

Comment: I cannot run it as a function and I need to clear the variables as in fact I don't run a single script, but a set of scripts with functions inside (it is a fature selection based on genetic algorithm with subsequent statistics script which is followed by exporting to a text file the best results). I woud need just one clear-proof variable for the external script.

Answer (score 0):

clearvars -except ...   works perfectly. Thank you Cebri